# Bayesian hierarchical exchangeability assumptions reasonable with a check treatment?

Tags: bayesian, multiple-comparisons, hierarchical-bayesian

**This is information I believe to be true**

- A practical feature of hierarchical Bayesian models is that partial pooling reduces (eliminates?) the need of adjusting for multiple comparisons when comparing groups.
  ([http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/multiple2f.pdf](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/research/published/multiple2f.pdf))
- Statistical rethinking 2nd ed page 419 seems to state that this hierarchical modeling can be applied to traditional fixed effects as long as "...the individual units are exchangeable".
- Bayesian data analysis 3rd ed page 104-106 suggest that having additional information about the relative size of a parameter value invalidates the exchangeability assumption.

**My problem**

- I work in an industry where correcting for multiple comparisons is standard procedure: it is often the case that pairwise comparisons are performed between 1- ~10 treatments.
- I would like to use a Bayesian hierarchical model that allows partial pooling for the treatment effects (mainly to avoid the multiple comparisons issue). Stan allows for some additional modeling flexibility that would be useful in my current situation.
- I prefer the idea of shrinking the effects towards a common mean rather than adjusting p-values, but I don't know that I can articulate why exactly. Probably because, in my experience, large estimates are usually due to chance and I like the idea of inserting a little more skepticism.

**My questions**

1. If I have 10 levels of some treatment (i.e. fertilizer) X and I suspect that treatment Xi (nitrogen fertilizer),  will have a larger effect on crop yield than treatment Xj (a check, no fertilizer) then is it inappropriate to use partial pooling to estimate all of the X effects?
2. If it is inappropriate then how exactly would partial pooling ever be justified for traditional "fixed effects"? We usually start an experiment with the assumption that at least some of the treatments will have an effect compared to the check (otherwise why bother?).

Thanks very much.

Comment: Side comment: sometimes analysts used hierarchical models when the groups are not exchangeable.  Where there are not too many groups one can use fixed effects, and these don't assume exchangeability.

Comment: Thanks for the response @FrankHarrell. Have reviewers ever raised the "non-exchangeability" issue as a sticking point in your previous papers? If so, how did you respond? (if you don't mind me asking)

Comment: I have not published many papers that used random effects.  The general ways that Bayes gets rid of multiple comparison problems are (1) such problems don't exist in parameter space like they do in (frequentist) sample space, and (2) priors for both fixed and random effects.  Priors on fixed effects such as shrinkage priors constrain large effects.  For example you can have priors that move fixed effects for a $k$-category predictor towards a constant.

Comment: For your point #1: Are you relying on the likelihood principle to hold? I don't think it does in my case. My employer wanted a new analysis from previously analyzed data, so my opinions are somewhat affected by the papers that have already been published. I have seen some of your previous comments about multiple comparisons in the Bayesian framework, but I get the feeling that they apply to confirmatory studies rather than pseudo-confirmatory/exploratory.

Comment: For your point #2, are you referring to something like a spike/slab model or maybe a cauchy prior (similar to solutions here https://betanalpha.github.io/assets/case_studies/modeling_sparsity.html)

Comment: The variety of priors is endless, and it depends on whether you are referring to random or to fixed effects.  For random effects papers have been published using a nonparametric random effects distribution and this has been put to good use in situations with huge N and huge number of clusters where you can document that the random effect distribution is bimodal.